# In IntelliJ, how to exclude \target\*.html files in search (everywhere) result?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a IntelliJ java project, there are some HTML file templates under my source folder. This project is built and output to \target\ folder. The HTML file templates are copied over to the target folder as well.

I have been trying to exclude the HTML files in target folder from "search everywhere" result.

**I have already set the \target folder as 'Excluded' in 'Project Structure settings'**.

But this is not working: although target*.java and target*.js are excluded in this way, the target*.html files are not. I think IntelliJ's 'Excluded' folder only exclude these files it considered as source files, but html is not.

Is there any workaround for this? I am using IntelliJ Idea 2016.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd do the following:

in your module settings on the Sources-Tab, in the right pane you click on the directory and then on "Excluded". The directory will then appear in the left pane as an "Excluded Folder"

I was satisfied by that, but it wasn't exactly what you wanted to achieve.

Would it be better to configure a custom scope? Try [this.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206336559-exclude-directory-from-search)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the target folder marked as excluded but also, partially, marked as source. This caused the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

With current Intellij versions, excluding the target folder (right click on folder -> Mark directory as -> Excluded) and then searching with selected tab "In Project" definitely does the trick. No more java.html in the search results.