# How to exclude folders/files from search everywhere in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3, when I perform a 'search everywhere' (Shift + Command + O on a Mac), my search results now include everything in my `target/` folders, which are set in my `Project Structure > Modules` as 'excluded'.  I've tried invalidating caches/restarting, [following documentation on their site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html), and searching related issues:

- [Search everywhere in intellij stoped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901358/search-everywhere-in-intellij-stoped-working)
- [In IntelliJ, how to exclude \target\*.html files in search (everywhere) result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135017/in-intellij-how-to-exclude-target-html-files-in-search-everywhere-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the exclusion and re-added it for each module in my project, then did an invalidate cache/restart to resolve the issue.

Comment: Tried this and it's still showing me class files from libraries in excluded folders :( Oddly, they're highlighted in brown, as if the IDE _knows_ it isn't supposed to be showing them.

Comment: I ran into something similar recently, try renaming your `./.idea/workspace.xml` file and restarting IntelliJ, forcing it to rebuild it.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, it still did not work. I still have a ton of stuff from my excluded library files in the Search Everywhere feature. I also have files from the PhpStorm plugins folder under C:\Program Files\PhpStorm\ in there that aren't even my project!